# How can I update my React component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently building out a contact form in React, and have a number of tags (interests) the user can select. I currently have a ContactForm and a Tag component, which is used when the data is mapped.

When the user clicks on a specific Tag, this should be added to the *tags* array if it's not already in the array, else if it already exists it should be removed from the array. This appears to work as required.

However, I also require the state of the Tag that's been clicked to be toggled between true/false. Given I already have an onClick for the Tag component, how can I pass down the state change to the Tag component?

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';

const Tag = ({ value, onClick, children }) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div key={key} onClick={onClick}>
      <span>{children || value}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const Tags = [
  { key: '1', title: 'Tag 1' },
  { key: '2', title: 'Tag 2' },
  { key: '3', title: 'Tag 3' },
];

const ContactForm: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (title) => {
    if(!tags.includes(title)) {
      setTags([...tags, title]);
    } 
    else {
      const updatedTags = tags.filter((el) => el !== title);
      setTags(updatedTags);
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      {Tags.map(({ title }, index) => {
        return (
          <Tag key={index} onClick={() => handleClick(title)}>
            {title}
          </Tag>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just provide your custom onClick in Tag component

```
const Tag = ({ value, onClick, children }) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleClicked = () => {
     setIsClicked(prevState => !preState);
     onClick();
  }

  return (
    <div key={key} onClick={handleClicked}>
      <span>{children || value}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner but i think that you can change it's state by just typing an if right under the "const handleClick" function, you check if it's false then setIsClicked(true) else the opposite.

```
const handleClick = (title) => {

//code added - change isClicked state right when you click    
if(isClicked === false){
  setIsClicked(true)
} else {
  setIsClicked(false)
}

if(!tags.includes(title)) {
  setTags([...tags, title]);
} 
else {
  const updatedTags = tags.filter((el) => el !== title);
  setTags(updatedTags);
}
```

}